# Service.onStartCommand() - is it possible to return more then one flag?

Tags: android, service, low-memory

I have to make sure that my `Service` will run until I'll explicitly call `stopService()`.
so I should return from `onStartCommand()` the `START_STICKY` flag.

also I want that in case my Service will be destroyed by the system because low memory, when the system will re-create it - the onStartCommand() will be called with the same intent originally started the service in the first place. 
because this reason - I would like to use the `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY` flag.
what I described surely can happened (and actually happened to me ones) according to the documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle

I know I can start the service with `startForground()`, that prevents the service been candidate for killed by the system when the memory is low, but I prefer not to use this approach, and anyway - according to the documentation: the system still can kill it under extreme low memory pressure.

so it would be perfect if I could return from `onStartCommand()` 
`START_STICKY|START_FLAG_REDELIVERY`

but according to the documentation it seems like you can use only one of the flags (maybe I'm wrong??).

so is it possible to start somehow service that will work in such a way as I described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant return multiple values. Instead, I would suggest you to return `START_STICKY` flag in `onStartCommand`. But for the first time, save the necessary values of intent's bundle in a `SharedPreference` storage. Next time, when your `onStartCommand` is re-called (after recovering from low memory or whatever reason) and the intent is found to be *null*, then simply load the values from preferences and keep on going with what ever you want.

Comment: I know I can implement such logic, but my question is if it possible to launch service as I describe, without that kind of "tricks"..

Comment: you cant return multiple values and this technique is not a hack or shortcut :)

Comment: anyway - I can't use shared preferences, because what I'm passing in the intent is a Messanger instance

Comment: It is possible. Since `Messenger` *implements* `Parcelable`, so you can easily convert it into *bytes* by using **writeToParcel** and later **marshall** from the returned `Parcel`. Anyhow, that was my suggestion, so its all up to how you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I guess that I'll save the messanger in the way you described or other way.  I want to except your answer, but what still missing to me is the answer to the simple question if it's possible or not to start service that is sticky + will deliver the same intent if restarts by the system.  you almost wrote it in the comment I upvoted.  if you know there's no such a thing - edit you answer, and I'll be glad to except it.

Answer (score 1):

the difference between `START_STICKY` and `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY` as far as I remember is just it will re-deliver with null intent or with the same intent again. It's just how you want to program it. You should return just one flag because they're different modes of operation.

Comment: are you sure about at? because that's not what can be understood from the documentation.

Comment: I could be wrong, but that's what I understand from the docs. Both will be re-started later on if it needs to be killed by the system. One will be re-started without an intent (null) and the other will be re-started with the same intent redelivered.

Comment: yes, but  START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT are used for services that should only remain running while processing any commands sent to them. I need my service to stay in background event if no one sent him a command for a while.

Comment: no one said anything about the NOT_STICK, which is a different one. The android system does not guarantee that any service will be always running. the best it can do is ask to be re-started. Maybe you should try a different approach? You could use the alarm manager to start your service every so often, or create an account on the account manager and make the whole synchronisation scheme (but it's a much more complex option). And I'm re-reading your question, back to the original point, I guess what you want is START_FLAG_REDELIVERY.